# Gmail Password- i can not find Xpath in PAssword, Code is write but not right Password

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
package Login;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Login 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Teknomines-5\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/gmail/about/");
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/a[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]")).sendKeys("Pratik.modh24@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]")).click();

        //Below Code password not print on PAssword textbox
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/content/section/div/content/div[1]/div/div[1]")).sendKeys("123");
        //driver.findElement(By.className("whsOnd zHQkBf")).sendKeys("123");
        //driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("test123");
        //driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("123");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("123456789");
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password > div:nth-child(1)")).sendKeys("123");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//INPUT[@name='password']")).sendKeys("******");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//INPUT[@type='password']/self::INPUT")).sendKeys("***");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//DIV[@class='aCsJod oJeWuf'])[1]")).sendKeys("123456");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password));
        password.sendKeys("your_password");     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPATH should select gmail "password input": `//input[@name='password']`

But you don't have to use XPATH, you can target the input field by lot of other ways. For instance I am using this (in Python):

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password'))).send_keys('my_password')
```

**EDIT**:
Also try changing the order of your commands to:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")));
password.sendKeys("your_password");
```

because you are creating the *password* variable `WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));` before you wait for it to appear on DOM: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password));`

Comment: i also try but not work, See link 
https://www.useloom.com/share/5faac64ffafa4ede81d2f9d1246a790c

Comment: I have edited my answer, please see the new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

this is working one

```
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/gmail/about/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/a[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]")).sendKeys("Pratik.modh24@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]/content/span")).click();
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    password.sendKeys("your_password");
```